# Multi-select dropdown angular-ui/ui-select

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, multi-select

So I'm working with [UI-select](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select) and I'm using the multiselect option so that I can have multiple selections in my inputbox. However I was also looking for a way to select multiple choices from the dropdown before submitting them in the input field.

I am talking about something similar to [this](http://dotansimha.github.io/angularjs-dropdown-multiselect/#/). I have searched around their github page but I can't seem to find if this even exists. I can not find any issues on it either, so I presume it has been implemented (can't imagine no one would have though of this before)

Comment: http://isteven.github.io/angular-multi-select/

Comment: Yes I know there are other projects that have this, but I would like to keep using the angular-ui team's component, I'm not interested in rewriting my view completely